# Embedded document cannot hold other model IDs ? undefined method `bson_type'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reference, mongoid

Either I still haven't understood the limitations of embedded documents, or it's a bug :

I want my notifications to have a reference to a "sender" user model. However, I don't care about being able to find the notifications sent by a given user. I thought this setup would work :

EDIT : the problem is coming from my custom setter

```
class User
  embeds_many :notifications

class Notification
  embedded_in :user
  belongs_to :sender, class_name: "User", inverse_of: nil

  def sender=(someone)
    self[:sender] = (someone.is_a?(User) ? someone : someone.user)
  end
```

Now in the console :

```
user_a.notifications.create!(sender: user_b)
```

Throws a

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `bson_type' for #<User:0x83dd590>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to kill myself now...

```
def sender=(someone)
  self[:sender] = (someone.is_a?(User) ? someone : someone.user).id
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help, might just be an observation.

`sender=` is overwriting the Rails method, so you might be getting some weirdness from that. I would do:

```
def sender=(someone)
  someone = someone.is_a?(User) ? someone : someone.user
  super(someone)
end
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Overriding the Mongoid method was my point. I had tried to do that before but it throws a `NoMethodError: super: no superclass method `sender='`

Comment: I realized that a Mongoid class doesn't inherit from Mongoid like ActiveRecord classes. Instead, they are included as modules, which is why super doesn't work.